# Segmentation fault when writing to an array

Tags: c++, arrays, syntax

I'm working on creating an empty array of fixed size and then writing to a specific index. However, when doing this with my pushFront() method I am receiving a segmentation fault.

After looking at the code with gdb:

```
(gdb) list
337            *  first element in the %vector.  Iteration is done in ordinary
338            *  element order.
339            */
340           const_iterator
341           begin() const
342           { return const_iterator (this->_M_impl._M_start); }
343
344           /**
345            *  Returns a read/write iterator that points one past the last
346            *  element in the %vector.  Iteration is done in ordinary
```

Compiling with -Wall:

```
file.cpp: In constructor ‘StringStuff::StringStuff(int)’:
file.cpp:18:20: warning: unused variable ‘elements’ [-Wunused-variable]
    vector<string>* elements = new vector<string>(2*guaranteedCapacity);
```

Which I'm not sure what to make of. My code is below, where I basically call a test function which attempts to add the string "test" to the array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class StringStuff{
    vector<string>* elements;
    int frontItem;
    int rearSpace;
    int upperBound;

    public:            
        StringStuff(int guaranteedCapacity) {
            vector<string>* elements = new vector<string>(2*guaranteedCapacity);
            frontItem = guaranteedCapacity;
            rearSpace = guaranteedCapacity;
            upperBound = 2 * guaranteedCapacity;
        }

        virtual void pushFront(string newItem){
            elements->at(--frontItem) = newItem; 
        }
        virtual void test01(){       
            pushFront("test");  
        }
};

/** Driver
 */
int main() {
    StringStuff* sd = new StringStuff(100);
    sd->test01();
}
```

Surely there must be a beginners mistake in here somewhere?

Comment: Try compiling with `-Wall`...

Comment: Interesting. I've updated the original question with the output from this..

Comment: The first 'beginner mistake' is that your code uses pointers. (And because of that it also leaks memory, and does not obey the Rule of Three.) You can easily remove all pointers and `new`s from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't

```
virtual void pushFront(string newItem){
    newItem = elements->at(--frontItem);
}
```

be

```
virtual void pushFront(string newItem){
    elements->at(--frontItem) = newItem;
}
```

?

And, looking at the hint -Wall gives you:

```
vector<string>* elements = new ...
```

should just be

```
elements = new ...
```

or you'll define another `elements` variable that lives just in the scope of the initializer function, and the class-wide elements variable will still be undefined when you call your tests.

Comment: It throws a segmentation fault either way.

Do I have this backwards? Instead of adding "test" to the array, I am assigning the element at --frontItem to a variable newItem?

Comment: Well, your OP says "which attempts to add the string "test" to the array.".

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to do, which I believe the current code is correct?